# Subcategory of functor category is complete

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, functors, monoidal-categories, operads

Let $D$ be a complete and cocomplete symmetric monoidal closed category (a Bénabou cosmos). Let $P$ be [the permutation category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/permutation+category). Consider the [substitution product](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/operad#DefinitionAsMonoid) $\circ$ on the functor category $[P^{op},D].$ Consider the subcategory of $[P^{op},D]$ consisting of $\circ$-monoids and $\circ$-monoid morphisms. Max Kelly [claims on page 2](https://www.emis.de/journals/TAC/reprints/articles/13/tr13.pdf) that this category is complete but not necessarily cocomplete.

I know that the category $[P^{op},D]$ is complete and cocomplete. But what about the subcategory of $\circ$-monoids? Are there some general theorems one can apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any monoidal category $\mathscr M$, one can form the category of monoids $\mathbf{Mon}(\mathscr M)$ in $\mathscr M$, which is equipped with a forgetful functor $U : \mathbf{Mon}(\mathscr M) \to \mathscr M$. (Note that the category $\mathbf{Mon}(\mathscr M)$ is not generally a *subcategory* of $\mathscr M$, because the objects of $\mathscr M$ may have more than one distinct monoid structure.) The forgetful functor $U$ [creates limits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/created+limit): explicitly, this means that it preserves and reflects limits, but more conceptually it means that limits in $\mathbf{Mon}(\mathscr M)$ are formed by taking the underlying limits in $\mathscr M$. Thus, if $\mathscr M$ is complete, then so is $\mathbf{Mon}(\mathscr M)$. This applies in particular to the given example of the substitution monoidal structure.

Note, however, that $U$ does not create *colimits*; more sophisticated conditions are required to ensure that $\mathbf{Mon}(\mathscr M)$ has colimits (see, for instance, Kelly's paper [A unified treatment of transfinite constructions for free algebras, free monoids,colimits, associated sheaves, and so on](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/unified-treatment-of-transfinite-constructions-for-free-algebras-free-monoids-colimits-associated-sheaves-and-so-on/FE2E25E4959E4D8B4DE721718E7F55EE)).